# Using Django-PayPal - PayPal IPN getting 401

Tags: paypal-ipn, http-status-code-401, django-paypal

I'm trying to setup Django-Paypal and have got as far as the return from PayPal. To cut a long story short, in my Apache access logs, I get the following whenever I process a payment through PayPal (and PayPal POSTs the result back to my server):

```
173.0.82.126 - - [27/Oct/2012:16:42:52 +0200] "POST /my/super/secret/notify/url/ HTTP/1.0" 401 787 "-" "-"
```

The notify view does have `@csrf_exempt` for the purpose of troubleshooting this error and still it doesn't work.

If anyone can tell me how to solve this issue (which is clearly a permissions/authorization issue), I'd be very grateful!

P.S.: I've tried adding `WSGIPassAuthorization` on to my apache config file, which also didn't help.

Comment: @Jay - thanks for the formatting corrections - I'm normally pretty good at getting that right, but I'm afraid my frustration with the problem at hand got the better of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, I was being very dim.... We had Basic Authentication on the server to keep out prying eyes until launch, so of course PayPal was being rejected with a 401.....

So the answer of course is to remove the Basic Authentication while testing the IPN - all clear!

Amazing how stepping back from something for a bit reveals the most glaring (and simple) of mistakes.

Comment: Often times, completely disabling HTTP Basic Auth is not an option. @pfwd's answer takes this into account by whitelisting only PayPal Sandbox IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I've Just hit the same issue but kept the basic authentication by adding a few 'Allow from' rules in the virtual host:

```
Allow from 173.0.82.77
Allow from 173.0.82.126
Allow from 173.0.82.78
Satisfy Any
```

[PayPal Sandbox ip addresses](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/250/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDA1MTU5NjcyL3NpZC9lYjdfOTVabA%3D%3D)